# Authenticating plain text password against md5 hash

Tags: authentication, encryption, joomla, md5, salt

Hello and thank you for reading,

I have a task to authenticate a un / pw pair against a password stored in a MySQL database which has joomla serving as the CMS / frontend.

The joomla web application supports storing usernames and passwords in said database and it would appear that it goes through the following steps when storing a new user -

```
$salt  = JUserHelper::genRandomPassword(32);
$crypt = JUserHelper::getCryptedPassword($array['password'], $salt);
$array['password'] = $crypt.':'.$salt;
```

genRandomPassword looks like -

```
/**
 * Generate a random password
 *
 * @static
 * @param   int     $length Length of the password to generate
 * @return  string          Random Password
 * @since   1.5
 */
public static function genRandomPassword($length = 8)
{
    $salt = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789";
    $len = strlen($salt);
    $makepass = '';

    $stat = @stat(__FILE__);
    if (empty($stat) || !is_array($stat)) $stat = array(php_uname());

    mt_srand(crc32(microtime() . implode('|', $stat)));

    for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i ++) {
        $makepass .= $salt[mt_rand(0, $len -1)];
    }

    return $makepass;
}
```

Finally, getCryptedPassword  and getSalt look like -

```
/**
 * Formats a password using the current encryption.
 *
 * @access  public
 * @param   string  $plaintext  The plaintext password to encrypt.
 * @param   string  $salt       The salt to use to encrypt the password. []
 *                              If not present, a new salt will be
 *                              generated.
 * @param   string  $encryption The kind of pasword encryption to use.
 *                              Defaults to md5-hex.
 * @param   boolean $show_encrypt  Some password systems prepend the kind of
 *                              encryption to the crypted password ({SHA},
 *                              etc). Defaults to false.
 *
 * @return string  The encrypted password.
 */
public static function getCryptedPassword($plaintext, $salt = '', $encryption = 'md5-hex', $show_encrypt = false)
{
    // Get the salt to use.
    $salt = JUserHelper::getSalt($encryption, $salt, $plaintext);

    // Encrypt the password.
    switch ($encryption)
    {
        case 'plain' :
            return $plaintext;

        case 'sha' :
            $encrypted = base64_encode(mhash(MHASH_SHA1, $plaintext));
            return ($show_encrypt) ? '{SHA}'.$encrypted : $encrypted;

        case 'crypt' :
        case 'crypt-des' :
        case 'crypt-md5' :
        case 'crypt-blowfish' :
            return ($show_encrypt ? '{crypt}' : '').crypt($plaintext, $salt);

        case 'md5-base64' :
            $encrypted = base64_encode(mhash(MHASH_MD5, $plaintext));
            return ($show_encrypt) ? '{MD5}'.$encrypted : $encrypted;

        case 'ssha' :
            $encrypted = base64_encode(mhash(MHASH_SHA1, $plaintext.$salt).$salt);
            return ($show_encrypt) ? '{SSHA}'.$encrypted : $encrypted;

        case 'smd5' :
            $encrypted = base64_encode(mhash(MHASH_MD5, $plaintext.$salt).$salt);
            return ($show_encrypt) ? '{SMD5}'.$encrypted : $encrypted;

        case 'aprmd5' :
            $length = strlen($plaintext);
            $context = $plaintext.'$apr1$'.$salt;
            $binary = JUserHelper::_bin(md5($plaintext.$salt.$plaintext));

            for ($i = $length; $i > 0; $i -= 16) {
                $context .= substr($binary, 0, ($i > 16 ? 16 : $i));
            }
            for ($i = $length; $i > 0; $i >>= 1) {
                $context .= ($i & 1) ? chr(0) : $plaintext[0];
            }

            $binary = JUserHelper::_bin(md5($context));

            for ($i = 0; $i < 1000; $i ++) {
                $new = ($i & 1) ? $plaintext : substr($binary, 0, 16);
                if ($i % 3) {
                    $new .= $salt;
                }
                if ($i % 7) {
                    $new .= $plaintext;
                }
                $new .= ($i & 1) ? substr($binary, 0, 16) : $plaintext;
                $binary = JUserHelper::_bin(md5($new));
            }

            $p = array ();
            for ($i = 0; $i < 5; $i ++) {
                $k = $i +6;
                $j = $i +12;
                if ($j == 16) {
                    $j = 5;
                }
                $p[] = JUserHelper::_toAPRMD5((ord($binary[$i]) << 16) | (ord($binary[$k]) << 8) | (ord($binary[$j])), 5);
            }

            return '$apr1$'.$salt.'$'.implode('', $p).JUserHelper::_toAPRMD5(ord($binary[11]), 3);

        case 'md5-hex' :
        default :
            $encrypted = ($salt) ? md5($plaintext.$salt) : md5($plaintext);
            return ($show_encrypt) ? '{MD5}'.$encrypted : $encrypted;
    }
}

/**
 * Returns a salt for the appropriate kind of password encryption.
 * Optionally takes a seed and a plaintext password, to extract the seed
 * of an existing password, or for encryption types that use the plaintext
 * in the generation of the salt.
 *
 * @access public
 * @param string $encryption  The kind of pasword encryption to use.
 *                          Defaults to md5-hex.
 * @param string $seed      The seed to get the salt from (probably a
 *                          previously generated password). Defaults to
 *                          generating a new seed.
 * @param string $plaintext The plaintext password that we're generating
 *                          a salt for. Defaults to none.
 *
 * @return string  The generated or extracted salt.
 */
public static function getSalt($encryption = 'md5-hex', $seed = '', $plaintext = '')
{
    // Encrypt the password.
    switch ($encryption)
    {
        case 'crypt' :
        case 'crypt-des' :
            if ($seed) {
                return substr(preg_replace('|^{crypt}|i', '', $seed), 0, 2);
            } else {
                return substr(md5(mt_rand()), 0, 2);
            }
            break;

        case 'crypt-md5' :
            if ($seed) {
                return substr(preg_replace('|^{crypt}|i', '', $seed), 0, 12);
            } else {
                return '$1$'.substr(md5(mt_rand()), 0, 8).'$';
            }
            break;

        case 'crypt-blowfish' :
            if ($seed) {
                return substr(preg_replace('|^{crypt}|i', '', $seed), 0, 16);
            } else {
                return '$2$'.substr(md5(mt_rand()), 0, 12).'$';
            }
            break;

        case 'ssha' :
            if ($seed) {
                return substr(preg_replace('|^{SSHA}|', '', $seed), -20);
            } else {
                return mhash_keygen_s2k(MHASH_SHA1, $plaintext, substr(pack('h*', md5(mt_rand())), 0, 8), 4);
            }
            break;

        case 'smd5' :
            if ($seed) {
                return substr(preg_replace('|^{SMD5}|', '', $seed), -16);
            } else {
                return mhash_keygen_s2k(MHASH_MD5, $plaintext, substr(pack('h*', md5(mt_rand())), 0, 8), 4);
            }
            break;

        case 'aprmd5' :
            /* 64 characters that are valid for APRMD5 passwords. */
            $APRMD5 = './0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';

            if ($seed) {
                return substr(preg_replace('/^\$apr1\$(.{8}).*/', '\\1', $seed), 0, 8);
            } else {
                $salt = '';
                for ($i = 0; $i < 8; $i ++) {
                    $salt .= $APRMD5 {
                        rand(0, 63)
                        };
                }
                return $salt;
            }
            break;

        default :
            $salt = '';
            if ($seed) {
                $salt = $seed;
            }
            return $salt;
            break;
    }
}
```

I'm no PHP or Joomla expert but I understand to a certain extent what is going on. I believe as far as an encryption algorithm goes, md5 is being used.

My question is -

What do I need to do to authenticate a un / pw combo against a password stored like this? Presently the salt isn't being stored along with the PW so what do I need to do here exactly? I don't need any code or pseudo-code I just need a clear list of steps to take. If you do feel like providing code I'm writing my application in Java.

EDIT -

Okay I've gotten further supplying the salt / crypto password to the authentication library I'm using however it is saying that they don't matched even after going through all the hasing / decryption. I guess I'll have to play around with this a bit more.

Using that example PW I supplied in the comment below, here's what my java code looks like :

```
SimpleAuthenticationInfo info = new SimpleAuthenticationInfo("TestUser",
            "564c6d2c10a7135fe0ddf0b21d1a1226", getName());
    info.setCredentialsSalt(new SimpleByteSource("B9YEkhvnV8pZ8BU7fvVlIVTbEux5N17J"));


    return info;
```

And this is the response I get -

```
Submitted credentials for token [org.apache.shiro.authc.UsernamePasswordToken - TestUser, rememberMe=false] did not match the expected credentials.
```

I guess I'm close but I'm still not there. Since we're not passing an algorithm name into the getCryptedPassword PHP function, I'm guessing that it's using the default which appears to be MD5. I wonder why this isn't working.

Thank you,

-Zachary Carter

Comment: After taking another look I believe the salt is being stored side by side with the password separated by a colon. An example password looks like

564c6d2c10a7135fe0ddf0b21d1a1226:B9YEkhvnV8pZ8BU7fvVlIVTbEux5N17J

so I'm guessing that B9YEkhvnV8pZ8BU7fvVlIVTbEux5N17J is the salt. I still could use more explanation though in terms of what I need to do to authenticate against this.

Comment: Get rid of that. Plain md5 sucks, even with a salt.

Comment: Not a very helpful comment. I didn't set up the database or the front end web app I'm just trying to authenticate users against it.

Comment: You should convince whoever the decision maker is that you need to replace the use of md5 with sha1.  If they ask why, tell them how much money Sony lost because of the PlayStation Network breach.

Comment: @Jonathan Plain sha1 is pretty much as bad as plain md5 for password hashing. He should replace it with bcrypt or PBKDF2.

Comment: 31 bits of entropy for a salt is pretty small too. All that code looks like it was written by somebody who had no idea what they were doing. Is that code part of joomla itself, or from another library?

Comment: @CodeInChaos: most PHP code is well insecure and crypto is generally horrible (look at the "RNG" used above, yipes): [getCryptedPassword](http://docs.joomla.org/API15:JUserHelper/getCryptedPassword) answers your question, I think.

Comment: @owlstead I've already filed an issue against their ingenious `genRandomPassword` function. http://joomlacode.org/gf/project/joomla/tracker/?action=TrackerItemEdit&tracker_id=32&tracker_item_id=28009 | If some homebrew crypto is bad, I can understand that. But AFAIK Joomla is a big popular php CMS, so *somebody* should have looked over their crypto.

Comment: It's part of joomla unfortunately. I'm talking to our web guy and we're going to come up with something more secure. Irregardless I figured out what was happening. Joomla was building the hash as plain-text pw + salt but when Shiro is authenticating it builds the hash as salt + plain-text pw. The solution was subclassing SimpleCredentialsMatcher and AbstractHash. I couldn't override the methods in the existing subclasses because they were all protected. It works now so we'll see about coming up with a new method of encryption soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Joomla was building the hash as plain-text pw + salt but when Shiro is authenticating it builds the hash as salt + plain-text pw. The solution was subclassing SimpleCredentialsMatcher and AbstractHash. I couldn't override the methods in the existing subclasses because they were all protected.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

Given a user name `$un` and a plain text password `$pw`:

```
jimport( 'joomla.user.helper' );
$userId = JUserHelper::getUserId( $un );
$user = JUser::getInstance( $userId );

$existingPasswordParts = explode( ':', $user->password );
$salt = $existingPasswordParts[1];
$crypt = JUserHelper::getCryptedPassword( $pw, $salt );
$password = $crypt . ':' . $salt;

if ( $user->password == $password )
{
  /* match */
}
```

The user is fetched, and the used salt is re-used to encrypt the plain text password. After that, both encrypted passwords can be compared against each other.
This should work on J1.6, J1.7 and J2.5.

Comment: Did you read anything I posted? I said I needed to do this in Java not PHP and I already posted the solution so this still wouldn't have worked.

Comment: Ok, I apologize. I guess I stopped reading precisely when I read "Joomla" and saw all that PHP code. If the Java equivalent code does not work, it very likely is due to the use of the MD5 function, which differs from java to php - not sure how or why.

Comment: As I explained in my answer, the problem was that Apache Shiro was doing the hash in the reverse order that Jommla was hash(salt+plain-textpw) vs hash(plain-text+salt).